# Styles in link tag should apply for entire page but not for specific HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have CSS link tag in my page. i want that CSS to be applied to the entire page but not to specific DIV tag and its children in the HTML .For example, in below code- i want the styles from theme.css to be applied to entire html but not to the DIV with ID "doNotApplyCss" and all its child elements.  is it possible using Jquery or CSS?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sample1"></div>
<div class="sample2"></div>
<div class="sample3"></div>
<em>apply css here</em>
<div class="Content" id="doNotApplyCss">
    <em>no EM styles should be applied here</em>
    <em>no EM styles should be applied here</em>
    <div class="sample1">sample1 styles should not be applied here
        <div>child div2</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

theme.css

```
div{font-family: "tahoma"}
em{ font-family:"san-serif"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `initial` for `doNotApplyCss` and it childrens ,this overlaps other css.

```css
div { 
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
em {
  font-family: 'Galada', cursive;
}

#doNotApplyCss, #doNotApplyCss * {
  font-family:initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Galada" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sample1">Ehsan</div>
<div class="sample2">Reza</div>
<div class="sample3">amin</div>
<em>apply css here</em>
<br>**********Start doNotApplyCss**********
<div class="Content" id="doNotApplyCss">
  <em>testing</em>
  <div>child Div1
    <div>child div2</div>
  </div>
</div>
**********End doNotApplyCss**********
```

Comment: thanks. but i dont want any styles to be applied in the "donotapplycss" Div

Comment: note that the css [`initial` keyword is not supported by any version of Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value)

Comment: @OneManBand , so insert default font name instead of `initial`.

Comment: Thank you . This helps. Hope I can use inherit as well . Please correct me if wrong

Answer (score 0):

Update: As Ehsan mentioned make the font-family initial so that it would fall back to the default font. But you don't need to add the same style for the children specifically as it will add it to the children by default.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#myId {
  font-family: initial;
}
```

```html
Test font

<div id="myId">Div content
<span>Children</span>
</div>
```

Yes you could apply a global style to the body and override that for your div with the id of `doNotApplyCss`,

```
body {
   font-family: "tahoma";
}

#doNotApplyCss {
   font-family: "san-serif" !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but i dont want any styles to be applied in the "donotapplycss" Div

Comment: What is the font you need to apply for the `doNotApplyCss`

Comment: i dont want to apply any font. it is not just about fonts., it is about any styles., i dont want the linked css to apply any style to the "donotapplycss" DIV